# Unchangeable script in Ubuntu

Tags: java, python, ubuntu

My client wants to setup a script/file in Ubuntu in one of my client's contractors system to monitor his work/sites visited etc as long as he is in office.

His contractor will have root access in the system, so how can we make sure that the file cant be changed ? Deleting wont help him as his boss will know that because he wont get the online reports anymore after deleting.

But he can change it to the way he wants. Actually, we can write a java.java file or python or some program file but I found that even java.class files and python.pyc files can also be decompiled.

So, he can easily know the program and can easily change it.

So, any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have legal issues taken care of, your only hope seem to be [Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) and [Security through Obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Go for languages which are tougher to decompile, such as C/C++ (see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185602/how-is-c-c-more-difficult-to-decompile-than-c))

1. Ensure that you collect a lot of data, and store all the data encrypted so the client cannot directly access it.
2. Try and obsfucate to hide away your encryption keys, as well as the encryption algorithm.
3. Send the data from the contractor's system to the server encrypted.
4. Possibly also monitor whenever the contractor killed your process.

Comment: Thanks, Akhil seems to be Indian name ? It is illegal in India ? Many MNCs monitor employees right. The only thing special here is my client owns a startup(not MNC) and it uses ubuntu(unlike windows in MNCS).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be *not* to do this.

Now I don't know about your country's legislation, but in mine, any solution of this sort would be highly illegal. If the client is worried about the contractor, there would be other means of "monitoring" them.

- Daily reporting
- Set up a proxy blacklisting sites, possibly enforcing it over network tools
- Actually *meet* the person and talk with them about their achievements, difficulties and such. Not *inquiring*, actually *caring* about how the project is going. If that doesn't motivate the contractor to work, nothing will.